# JSF update automatically generated ID

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have following code (i tried also ui:repeat which gives same result):

```
<p:dataList value="#{bean.objects}" var="object" type="none" id="objects" rowIndexVar="index">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton update=":objects:#{index}:dialog" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="dialog">
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:dataList>
```

And i want update element with ID "dialog" but it just not working:

> Cannot find component with expression :objects:0:dialog referenced from objects:0:j_idt35.

How i can update elements on different level when i have generated context?

Comment: Why do you nest an `<h:form>` inside a `<p:dataList>`?

Comment: I have multiple objects on one page (like forms, tables) they have definition in database so i need iterate over collection "objects" and render proper components (dialogs, dataTables, forms, ...). It works pretty fine util i want update element on different level.

Comment: why not put `p:dataList` in a single form and use `process="@this"` on each `p:commandButton`?

Comment: this is not efficient solution because first form can be huge dataTable and i don't want to process everything again when it's not necessary (i want show just little dialog for example)

Comment: well, that's what `process` attribute is for.

Comment: I can't work with ID so i can't use process neither :/

Comment: the only thing you submit in that form is the commandButton, so you can just use `process="@this"`. seriously, repeating forms is not a good practice.